# Javascript runs After page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript method that runs, which hides certain parts of the screen, based on some values, which are sourced from a property in my MVC view model.

```
<body onload="TransferAmountDisplayToggle(@Model.EntityEventTypeId)">
```

When the screen loads, all controls are visible for around half a second, and then the controls hide, and the screen is ready.

Is there anyway to stop this from happening? i.e. Not show the screen until the javascript is complete?

Comment: Use a class on the `<body>` to hide everything, let the code run, and then remove that class.

Answer (score 2):

You an hide the body with the `visibility: hidden;`

```
<body style="visibility:hidden;" onload="TransferAmountDisplayToggle(@Model.EntityEventTypeId)">
```

Then at the bottom of the `TransferAmountDisplayToggle()` JavaScript function, add:

```
$('body').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Modifying `display` instead of `visibility` is an option, but I prefer to use `visibility` because sometimes there's JavaScript code that needs to check the width/height of elements and using `display: none;` can mess that up.

Comment: Thanks! I moved the visibility to the main Div, as the body seemed to cause a strange issue. Now, the main frame is simply blank, until load. Perfect. Thanks!